# Pythagorean Theorem using custom functions in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make pythagorean theorem using custom functions in google sheets. I want it to be able to find any missing side by doing =PYTH(a,b,c). here is my current code:

```
function PYTH(a,b,c){
  if(c = 0){return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2)+Math.pow(b, 2)))};
  if(b = 0){return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2)-Math.pow(a, 2)))};
  if(a = 0){return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2)-Math.pow(b, 2)))};
};
```

I have tried using if functions to see when something is missing by checking if they equal "" and checking if they equal 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you have the logic correct and it should work, however there is one small detail you missed.

Here is a functional version.

```
function PYTH(a,b,c){
  if(c == 0){return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2)+Math.pow(b, 2)))};
  if(b == 0){return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2)-Math.pow(a, 2)))};
  if(a == 0){return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c, 2)-Math.pow(b, 2)))};
};
```

For the if statements when comparing the variables to 0, you need double or triple "=" signs to do the comparison.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I know it was a simple fix but still, I'm far more used to other coding languages so ill take any help I can get.

Comment: All good brother. Good luck with the rest of it!